# javascript alert box contain button with a class

Tags: javascript, alert

how to do a javascript alert box that contain a button with a class like this submit button:

```
<input type="submit" class="lightbox">
```

or there is any way to make a javascript form that pop up and contain this submit button?

Answer (score 1):

I would use this code:

```
var doc = document, htm = doc.documentElement, bod = doc.body;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
function winOpen(clickId, url, name, height, width){
  var ht = innerHeight || htm.clientHeight || bod.clientHeight;
  var wd = innerWidth || htm.clientWidth || bod.clientWidth;
  ht = (height-ht)/2; wd = (width-wd)/2;
  E(clickId).onclick = function(){
    open(url, name, 'height='+height+',width='+width+',top='+ht+',left='+wd);
  }
}
// You would use this like 
winOpen('newWindow', 'wherever.html', 'windowName', 500, 500);
```

`whatever.html` should be the page with your `lightbox` class.

Comment: i don't want to open a new browser page i want to open a small box that contain 1 button. But i understand what you mean and it's a really good idea but will need lot of work in my case.

Comment: You can set the size of the window, and the position.

Comment: is this what you mean http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_openwindow ?

Answer (score 1):

Standard browser alerts are not stylable - it will have to be done in code. If you don't want to `window.open` a new page and willing to use a 3rd party library - [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message) is a good choice. The Dialog is fully stylable- yes, including button.